# Displaying a single EmberJS DS.Model from a FixtureAdapter Store in a template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to update the Ember-Brunch (original repository: https://github.com/icholy/ember-brunch) to the latest EmberJS and EmberJS-Data frameworks.  The current problem I have is I am trying to convert the original Bob model into a `DS.Model` using a `DS.FixtureAdapter` in the `DS.Store`.  But whatever I try I run into issues getting the data to display.  Here are a couple attempts:

With the route:

```
App.BobRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() { 
        return App.Bob.find();
    }
});
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of null

And if I switch to this route:

```
App.BobRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function() {
        App.BobController.set('content', App.Bob.find());
      }
});
```

I get the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object App.BobController has no method 'set'
>   app.js:184 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of
>   null

Any ideas?

You can see my current work https://github.com/seankeating/ember-brunch and my attempt to do this in the DS.Model-Implementation-For-Using-Local-DSStore branch.

**Store:**

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create()
});
```

**Controller:**

```
App.BobController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

});
```

**Model:**

```
var App = require('app'),
    attr = DS.attr;

App.Bob = DS.Model.extend({

    firstName : attr('string'),
    lastName  : attr('string'),
    lyrics    : attr('string'),

    fullName: function(){
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')

});

App.Bob.FIXTURES = [{
    firstName: 'bob',
    lastName: 'marley',
    lyrics: 'no woman no cry!'
}];
```

**Template:**

```
<h2>{{fullName}}'s page!</h2>
<button class="btn btn-success" {{action doClick target="view"}}>click me</button>
{{#linkTo home}}<button class="btn" {{action doHome}}>go back home</button>{{/linkTo}}
```

Comment: Can you supply the stack trace that you get with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of null". It should work but that error does not provide enough information.

Also, are you using the debug build of Ember? It provides much more informative errors than the minified build.

Comment: I think this is simply because you miss the id in the object fixture. Keep in mind the initial fixtures must mimics what the backend gives.

Comment: @sly7_7 settings the id in the FIXTURES did correct the problem for both implementations.  But I still have the issue of it displaying Bob's data.  With just the .find() the pages show up but the template isn't populated.  Then trying the specific object with its id, App.Bob.find({id: 0});, or with its name, App.Bob.find({firstName: 'bob'}); the template isn't populating.  Any ideas here?

Comment: @YehudaKatz I'm not using the debug build, I am going to look for the latest one now. v > v1.0.0-pre.2-291-g4785901

Comment: @SeanKeating would it be possible to provide a jsfiddle or jsbin ? You should be able to use this: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/beyGr/ as a starting, not sure this is exaclty the same version as yours.

Comment: Something that may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/beyGr/5/

Comment: @sly7_7 Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/beyGr/7/

Comment: @sly7_7 maybe I am approaching this wrong by setting the content when I want to just show the single object 'bob' on that page?  Previously they were sending a model in via connectOutlet, but I wanted to use the datastore for the model. https://github.com/icholy/ember-brunch/blob/master/app/router.js.  I was looking to do a similar task with renderTemplate but I didn't see how to pass in the model that way.

Comment: @SeanKeating I think there is indeed a problem when using directly a model (usually should use dynamic segment). I tried to play with serialize/deserialize hook, but I can't make it work... perhaps Yehuda will have the answer

Comment: Debugging a bit, I had "<.BobRoute:ember261>" in a toString route... I guess this was a previous version of the router. Would it be possible to update agains latest-master ?

Comment: finally got it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/beyGr/18/

Comment: Wow so the id in the FIXTURES had to be in quotes to work huh?

Comment: Sean Keating: That is a known issue that I forgot about. It should be fixed ASAP.

Comment: @sly7_7 do you want to write up an answer or should I?

Comment: Sean Keating: Actually, thanks to sly7_7, that was fixed in https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/bc755f9227d9a71f33e4dc8b675409de66fe8fd2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before [bc755f9](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/bc755f9227d9a71f33e4dc8b675409de66fe8fd2), you needed to supply your fixture keys as Strings, which is how Ember Data stores them internally.

Now, you can use either numbers or strings as fixture IDs, and everything will work as expected.

Separately, you should always use the debug build of Ember.js in development, which provides much better error messages should something go wrong. As of [ea6922f](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/ea6922f82b7592707a222c1e83cbcda728d1e6ca), the production build of Ember.js will warn you if you are running it in `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.